# php calculate percentage with decimal answer

Tags: php

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.  I've got a number, eg 220.  Then I need to increase it with for example 11%, so 220 * 11% = 244.2, but my answer is 2420?

I've tried the following:

```
        echo '<br>';
        echo $col0 . '<br>'; //outputs 220

        settype($col0New, "decimal");
        $col0New = ($col0 * '11%') + $col0;

        echo $col0New    . '<br>'; //outputs 2640 but should be 244.2?

        $col0New1 = number_format($col0New,2);
        echo $col0New1   . '<br>'; //outputs 2,640.00
```

Please help.

Comment: No need to do it so complex, you can simply do `220 * 1.11` - which outputs `244.20`

Comment: Thanks, can you please put it in an answer so i can accept?

Comment: BTW. There is no "decimal" type in settype options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for making it any more complex than you need. Basic math allows you to just multiply with a constant, more specific, if you multiply by `1.11`, you'll get an increase of 11%.

You can simply do it like this

```
echo $col0 * 1.11; // Outputs 244.20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `%` as percentage in `php`. To Accompish what you want, you need to rewrite your percentage to it's decimal form. Ex: `55%` will be `0.55`

Answer (score 0):

You need to stay with pure numbers: 240 * 1.11. Your '11%' is a string literal, which PHP must fist convert to the number 11, and then multiplies by 240, which explains where 2420 comes from.

.11 is 11%, but you want to add 1 to increase the value to get 111%.